# How to add text box value to hyperlink in C# on windows form?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I need to create a hyperlink that takes the input from textbox and display the web page. 
textbox value is dynamically generated. The web page generated depends on the ext box value. Somebody can help Me please

Thanking you in Advance

Comment: You should post your code so people can see what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bare minimum, as you didn't specify which behavior do you expect, but it may work for you or give you a hind. Also check `LinkLabel` control description in MSDN

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            linkLabel.Text = "Click to search!";
            linkLabel.LinkClicked += LinkLabel_LinkClicked;
        }

        private void LinkLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            string googleSearch = @"https://www.google.com/?q=";
            Process.Start(googleSearch + textBox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

To check it just add `TextBox`, name it `textBox` and `LinkLabel` named `linkLabel`. When you enter something into text box and click on label google search with this phrase will start in your default browser.

Comment: Hello, can I do the same way in wpf`?

Comment: yes, this pretty much works the same, but it's very basic. think about using binding(since you wan't to use WPF, it's one of basic mechanisms and worth to know) or updating your variable as you type if it will be used for some ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

For WPF,
In xaml code,

```
        <Hyperlink RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" NavigateUri="https://www.google.de/search?q=">LINK

        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
```

Implement Hyperlink_RequestNavigate function in xaml.cs

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender,   System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri+textBox.Text));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

//textbox.Text contains the text to be appended